# What periodic functions have to do with rational numbers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rational-numbers, periodic-functions

I would like to understand why is the answer of this question letter d.

### Question:

The solution φ(t) = (x (t) , y(t), z(t), w(t)) of the system of equations:

x' =y, y' = - x, z' =w, w' =-(k^2)*z, that satisfies φ(0) = (1,0,0,1) is periodic.

So, is correct to say:

a) k is a whole number
b) k = 0
c) k > 0

### d) k is a rational number different of zero

e) k is not a rational number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this system is made of functions with two distinct periods: $2\pi$ and $2k\pi$. For the solution to be globally periodic, $k$ must be rational, let $\dfrac pq$, so that after $q$ period for the second, you have seen $p$ periods of the first.

---

In other words, rational numbers have to do with periodic functions in that the respective periods must be commensurable.

Comment: still dont get it :(
Why they get 2 periods?
I think I lack information. Can u explain to someone not so good in hard math?
I solve the equations to t, tried to change for t + p(period), but i cant understand why have to be Rational.

Comment: @FELINTONETO: solve the equations, they are easy.