# What periodic functions have to do with rational numbers (2)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rational-numbers, periodic-functions

Two harmonic oscillators satisfying 
$$
\begin {cases}
x (0) = y (0) = 1 \\
 x '(0) = y' (0) = 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
,have movements governed by the equations
$$
\begin {cases}
x '' = - x \\
y '' = - Ky \\
\end{cases}
$$ , respectively, with $K> 0$. The function $f (t) = (x (t), y (t))$ is periodic if and only if:

### answer:

$\sqrt {k}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$ (rational numbers)

Can someone explain me why is the answer this?

Comment: Do you know what the closed-form solution to $y'' = -Ky$ is? It's hard to write a good answer without knowing exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Intuition: Imagine two pendulums oriented at right angles, initially displaced and each kicked towards the crossing point. They have different frequencies, but each return to their initial position with their initial velocity at times $T_{1}, 2T_{1}, 3T_{1}, \ldots$ and $T_{2}$, $2T_{2}$, $3T_{2}, \ldots$ respectively, where $T_{1}, T_{2}$ are the respective periods. Being periodic is equivalent to these two sequences eventually having two terms in common (at different positions). This is equivalent to $T_{1}/T_{2}$ being rational, which is equivalent to $\sqrt K$ being rational.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, so.. I know how to solve the ODEs of second order. X giving a exponential equation, and Y a periodic equation (i think) whith cos(sqrt(k)t) +1/sqrt(k) *sin(sqrt(k)t), right? from there, i dont understand the relation between sqrt(x) beeing rational number.. :/
y''=-ky i think is the elastic force (aceleration) of mass 1?
If u can help understanding.. i will really appreciate.

Comment: @preferred_anon, man! I think I start to understand it. :D.. But i wish have an analitical answer..:/

Comment: The analytic solution to simple harmonic motion is extremely easy to find links to - for example: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Physics_(Advancing_Physics)/Simple_Harmonic_Motion/Mathematical_Derivation

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of your earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538374/what-periodic-functions-have-to-do-with-rational-numbers, which actually has a valid answer.